# Iterator Dereferencing

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator, dereference

I am using a vector in c++,

```
vector<Agents> agentlist;
```

Why does this work,

```
(agentlist.begin() )->print();
```

and this not?

```
*(agentlist.begin() ).print();
```

Isn't it valid to dereference an iterator using `*`?

Comment: You don't need the parentheses around `agentlist.begin()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), `.` has higher precedence than `*`

```
*(agentlist.begin()).print();
```

represents as:

```
*((agentlist.begin()).print());
```

While iterator has no `.print()` function call, compiler will throw out compile error.

You need:

```
 agentlist.begin()->print();  or  (*agentlist.begin()).print();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `(*(agentlist.begin())).print();` :)